# Is there a structure like `std::array<type, max_size>` where its "in use" size can be smaller than max_size?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, std

I have a problem where I use add, subtract and multiply lots of vectors of doubles (`std:vector<double>`). Each vector can have anywhere from 2 to 8 elements, The number of elements of a vector can change depending on the operation, but will never exceed  8.

The most speed efficient way to do this would be to use a types such as `double my_vector[8]` or  `std::array<double, 8> my_vector`. But then I'd still need a separate variable `int my_vector_size` to keep track of how many of the 8 preallocated slots the vector is actually using. Ie. if `my_vector_size = 2`, then the we consider the vector to be as `{my_vector[0],my_vector[1]}` with the rest of them being ignored until some operation changes   `my_vector_size` .

The next step would be to group `double my_vector[max_size]` and `int my_vector_size` into a single structure. But I'm wondering if `std` already has a structure that fits my requirements.

Comment: Are you restricted to the standard library (a.k.a. `std`), or would you consider [a third-party library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.small_vector)?

Comment: Can you use a std::vector with space for eight elements reserved?  This way the size would be whatever you put in it but there is room for eight elements without having to reallocate memory.

Comment: @ Anon Mail
For the types of operations I'm doing (additions, subtractions, multiplication or division by constants), something with an array structure intuitively seems the fastest (don't need insertion or deletion. Also, as the vectors move around a lot,  it reduces the number of required allocations).  I haven't tested using reserve yet . Maybe it will improve performance. 
 @ JaMiT those do seem interesting, but unfortunately I'm somewhat restricted in what libraries they're allowing us to use.

Comment: @user3257842 You should separate replies into separate comments. The "replying in comments" feature supports only one reply per comment. I believe it also fails to work when there is a space between the `@` and the user's name. See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more info.

Comment: @user3257842 when you reserve space in a vector, the vector does not "move around a lot". The entire point of reserve to to preallocate memory so adding elements to a vector does not cause a reallocation of memory.

Comment: A `std::vector` using a [`std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/monotonic_buffer_resource) would achieve both the functionality and absence of free store allocations requested here, but from contextual clues, this feels like a premature optimization.  _"The vectors move around a lot"_ does not describe what happens to a `std::vector` when _usage_ is within _capacity_ and would be much more correct than a `std::array` if usage ever exceeds capacity.